# Running several infinite loops with async/await

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, xamarin

I am developing android messanger app based on xamarin and .net 5 async/awaits.

In my app i have producer/consumer pattern for processing messages which is made on infinite loops.

for example ReadTcpClientAsync producer:

```
async Task ReadTcpClientAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    cde.Signal();
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        byte[] buffer = await atc.ReadAsync(cancellationToken);
        // queue message...
    }
}
```

or SendStatementsAsync consumer which deque messages and awaits WriteAsync

```
private async Task SendStatementsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var nextItem = await _outputStatements.Take();
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        // misc ...
        await atc.WriteAsync(call.Serialize());
    }
}
```

and some consumers just await on Take calls

```
 var update = await _inputUpdateStatements.Take();
```

this construction works pretty well on tests, but there is one method where i think i made a huge mistake.
this method intent to run entire client backend, starting 3 pro/con while (true) loops simultaneously.

here it is:

```
public async Task RunAsync()
{
   _isRunning = true;
   _progress.ProgressChanged += progress_ProgressChanged;
    await InitMTProto(_scheme).ConfigureAwait(false); // init smth...
    // various init stuf...     
    await atc.ConnectAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); // open connection async
    // IS IT WRONG?
    try
    {                                   
        await Task.WhenAny(SendStatementsAsync(_cts.Token),
                               ReadTcpClientAsync(_cts.Token),
                               ProcessUpdateAsync(_cts.Token, _progress)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
    {   

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Forget about android for now, think any UI (WinForm, WPF, etc) OnCreate method in UI context to call RunAsync

```
protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    // start RA 
    await client.RunAsync()
    // never gets here - BAD, but nonblock UI thread - good
    Debug.WriteLine("nevar");
}
```

so, as you can see **there is a problem**. I can't do anything after RunAsync await call because it will never returns from Task.WhenAny(...). And i need perform status check there, but i need this pro/cons methods started, because my check wait on ManualResetEvent for it:

```
if (!cde.Wait(15000))
{
    throw new TimeoutException("Init too long");
}
```

Also, my check is async too, and it works like a charm :)

```
public async Task<TLCombinatorInstance> PerformRpcCall(string combinatorName, params object[] pars)
{
    // wait for init on cde ...
    // prepare call ...

    // Produce
    ProduceOutput(call);

    // wait for answer
    return await _inputRpcAnswersStatements.Take();
}
```

I think i should use another approach for starting this infinite loops, but i already have async Task methods all the way - so i really have no idea what to do.
Any help please?

Comment: Look at BlockingCollection

Comment: Just don't `await` `RunAsync()`?

Comment: @Blam i have my own realization of IProducerConsumer and it works pretty well, i do not need another one.

Comment: @svick that exactly what i do. But await RunAsync in IL creates ContinueWith construction, where all statements next line after RunAsync will be. So they will never be executed, because RunAsync WhenAny never trigger (except cancelation, but it is irrelevant)

Comment: What I meant is that you should try calling `RunAsync()` but **without `await`** (assuming you're okay with ignoring any exceptions it throws).

Comment: @svick ow, you told **don't**. Damn night :)

Comment: @svick But what it will produce? Will Task.WhenAny starts async tasks as expected? I saw some Poll example in official guide "The Task-based Asynchronous Pattern", but there are no any examples how to start that Poll task.

Comment: Your own realization is not doing what you need and that is a reason not to consider an exiting producer consumer collection?

Comment: @Blam you probably misunderstand my question. It's not about pro/con collections - they works fine as expected, it's **about starting several "infinite" tasks simultaniosly** and **under Task-based Async Pattern**. Maybe i have a huge misunderstanding of TAP in this situation, i don't know, that's why i ask it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of reading (nothing found) and @svick's advice i decided to call this methods without "await" as separate Task.Run's.
Aso i decided to run it in ThreadPool.

My final code is:

```
try
{                                   
    /*await Task.WhenAny(SendStatementsAsync(_cts.Token), 
           ReadTcpClientAsync(_cts.Token),
           ProcessUpdateAsync(_cts.Token, _progress)).ConfigureAwait(false);*/
    Task.Run(() => SendStatementsAsync(_cts.Token)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Task.Run(() => ReadTcpClientAsync(_cts.Token)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Task.Run(() => ProcessUpdateAsync(_cts.Token, _progress)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Trace.WriteLineIf(clientSwitch.TraceInfo, "Worker threads started", "[Client.RunAsync]");
}
```

Everything works fine as expected..
i'm not sure what problems it will cause in exception handling, as i know they will be lost

Of course such calls produce warning

> Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method
>   continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await'
>   operator to the result of the call.

which can be easily suppressed this way

```
// just save task into variable
var send = Task.Run(() => SendStatementsAsync(_cts.Token)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Also, if anyone know better solution i will be grateful to hear it.

Comment: This is a very old thread, but I am approaching a similar situation and just wondered with benefit of hindsight if you would do it differently?

Comment: @tank104 Yes, probably. Utilize whatever xamarin/droid/ios provides as a solution for background work.